# How to create product from image

Tags: commerce, media

I'm quite desperate right now and pretty newbie with Drupal. Anyhow, I wan't to develop my WordPress site and change this current system to Drupal. So now i'm able to set user specified galleries and images for customer to Proof images.

I should also make customer galleries that shows products by customer. 
Currently I'm creating galleries for customer and they can purchase images: Canvas, prints and digital downloads on specified image.

Is there way to create products once I upload images to Drupal?

One image could be sold in various different ways Like:

Digital image:

- 2048 px size
- Full Image size

Canvas:

- 20x30cm
- 30x40cm
- 40x55cm

Ans so on. 
At this point im using Sunshine Photochart for that, but it's kinda messy design.

Comment: You question is very broad, I suggest you look into commerce or ubercart module and try to setup a basic commerce site and than come up with specific questions to any problem you face.

Comment: `Is there way to create products once I upload images to Drupal?` If you download and install **[Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)**, then you can create products... you would upload the images while creating a product.

Comment: I know how to create single product and add image to single product. But problem is that i have like 40 pics that can be combined to those variations and i upload 40 images to customer at one session. With std product creation that is way to manual job. 

There is and i have allready purchased some modules for wordpress, but that platform sucks and is quite terrible nowadays. 

https://www.imagely.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin/pro-ecommerce-demo/